403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. On uploading CSV file or data more then 437 rows. ASP.NET MVC C#
Why am I encountering a "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied" error when attempting to upload a CSV file or data containing more than 437 rows in my ASP.NET MVC C# application? The website is hosted on AWS EC2 instance.

Can you show us your code and the exact error message? Also, exactly how large is the file that fails? Does it work if you remove sufficient rows? (If so, how big is it when it works?)

It is working fine on localhost. But when I test after deployment I am getting forbidden error. If number of rows are more then 437 even in csv I am getting the error.

You should start by comparing which credentials are being used on (A) localhost and (B) the EC2 instance. Since the error is related to permissions, it is likely that they code is running with a different set of permissions on the EC2 instance. Also, please answer the above questions.

Can you show us your code and the exact error message?
Answer: I don't know which part to show.
Also, exactly how large is the file that fails?
Answer: greater then 7.26kb
Does it work if you remove sufficient rows? (If so, how big is it when it works?)
Answer: Yes, if less then or equals to 7.26kb.
The file can be text or csv. Facing same error in both cases.
I am using OKTA for account management. If I use live db on localhost it works fine too. But on server it produces above error.
